# Find $P(Z_1>0, Z_2<0)$

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, actuarial-science

Let $Z_t$ be standard Brownian motion.

I would do $$P(Z_1>0, Z_2<0) {= P(Z_1>0 | Z_2<0) P(Z_2<0)\\=P(Z_1-Z_0>0 | Z_2-Z_0<0) P(Z_2-Z_0<0) \\=^{(*)} P(Z_1-Z_0>0)P( Z_2-Z_0<0) P(Z_2-Z_0<0) }$$
Where the asterisk means it is because of independent increments. The figures come from the fact that $(Z_t - Z_0)$ ~ $N(0,t-0)$.

According the solutions, it doesn't have what I have written. Why can't I do what I have done here?

Comment: What does $P(Z_1,Z_2)$ mean?

Comment: sorry fixed now

Comment: $Z_1-Z_0$ and $Z_2-Z_0$ are not independent. Moreover, if $X$ and $Y$ independent, then $P(X>0|Y<0)=P(X>0)$ and not $P(X>0)P(Y<0)$.

Comment: @NCh is it because they are overlapping increments?

Comment: @cooldudeman Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be a Brownian motion.

We have that:
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{P}\left(Z_1 > 0, Z_2 < 0\right) &= \mathbb{E}[1_{Z_1 > 0} 1_{Z_2 < 0}] \\
                 &= \mathbb{E}[1_{Z_1 > 0}\mathbb{E}[1_{Z_2-Z_1 < -Z_1}|Z_1] \\
                 &= \mathbb{E}[1_{Z_1 > 0}\mathbb{E}[1_{X < -Z_1}|Z_1]]  \text{ where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and independent of $Z_1$ }\\
&= \mathbb{E}[1_{Z_1 > 0}\Phi(-Z_1)] \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}\Phi(-x)\phi(x)dx = \frac12\left[\Phi(x)^2\right]^0_{-\infty} = \frac18 
\end{align}
Where $\Phi$ is the c.d.f of unit normal r.v. and $\phi$ is its p.d.f

Maybe there is a simpler way to arrive at this conclusion...

Comment: I don't think you want that factor of $x$ in your integrand.

Comment: Yes, typo! Corrected, thanks